# Please help me with line 8 of the code below?

Tags: matlab, random, poisson

Some one gave me this code to implement but I am not able to understand what Line 8 does in the code below. What does this mean y(y

```
clear;
lambda=0.1;
T=100;
M=50;
for i=1:M
 x=exprnd(1/lambda,1,2*lambda*T);
 y=cumsum(x);
pp{i}=y(y<T);
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If line 8 is `pp{i} = y(y < T)`, then it's creating a "cell array" (so now you can google it) with the `{}` syntax and setting element `i` to all the values in `y` that are less than `T` (i.e. 100)`. That is:

```
y<T
```

is an array the size of `y` with `1` in the places where the corresponding element of `y` is less than `T`.

```
y(y<T)
```

is then selecting only those elements. So it is probably smaller than `y`, and all the entries are less than `T`.

And then:

```
pp{i} = y(y<T)
```

is assigning that array to element `i` of a "cell array". Cell arrays are like normal arrays except that each element can be a different type or a different size.

Answer (score 0):

it means, retrieve all items of vector `y` where `y[i] < T`

see also the `find` method